# Using python sort() to sort a json file - TypeError

Tags: python, json, sorting

I've imported a json file into a python variable in order to sort it by values.
It looks something like this:

```
import json

def custom_sort(package):
   return package['analytics']

with open('my_file.json','r') as f:
   data=json.load(f)

data.sort(key=custom_sort)
```

This is the data in the json file:

```
[
  {
   "name": "a2ps",
   "desc": "Any-to-PostScript filter",
   "analytics": 
    { "install_30d": 77,
      "install_90d": 322,
      "install_365d": 1146 }
  },
  {
   "name": "a52dec",
   "desc": "Library for decoding ATSC A/52 streams (AKA 'AC-3')",
   "analytics":
    { "install_30d": 41,
      "install_90d": 153,
      "install_365d": 619 }
  },
]
```

And I get the following error:

```
data.sort(key=custom_sort)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Does anyone know why "sort()" doesn't work? The same happens with "sorted()".
(The data type of the variable "data" is a list).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like?

Comment: Because, presumably, for at least two items in your list, `package['analytics']` will return a `dict` object. ` dict1 < dict2` is not a defined operation, hence the error

Comment: You can provide a more specific sort operation for your dict objects, or worst case, just sort the json chunks themselves, e.g. `custom_sort => json.dumps(package['analytics'], sort_keys=True)`

Comment: I've added how the data I'm working with looks like. Thank you guys!

Comment: As juanpa.arrivillaga said, I was indeed having an item that had 'Null' values instead of integers, hence the error I was getting. Thank you everyone for your help! :)